# Can we not give the name for a tensor in tf.get_variable in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

In `tf.get_variable()`, there is a need to give a name for a variable. In contrast, it is not a must to specify names for variables in `tf.Variable()` function and tensorflow will give tensors default names. So, is there any trick for allowing us to omit manual name specification.

Comment: Can you share the code you're working on?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that can't be done. As the main aim for `tf.get_variable()` is to search for a variable with the same name first and if it didn't find it it creates a new one. So if you just want to create a new variable use `tf.Variable()` instead